# How to define GPIO pins in ROS on a Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a Raspberry pi 2 with ubuntu 14.04 and ros Indigo installed. I want to make a robot which would make a map of the surroundings and then autonomously navigate in it. I have sonars and no other sensors. So my question is how can write the GPIO code in ROS node thats going to publish and populate my range/sensor.msg so that my Raspberry Pi can communicate with the sonars?

It would also be help full if you can take a look at this question and see if you can help.
http://answers.ros.org/question/231269/can-i-rely-on-the-navigation-tutorials-when-working-with-sonar/

Thanks & Regards,
Mukut

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232819/how-to-define-gpio-pins-in-ros-on-a-raspberry-pi-2?/) by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) on 2016-04-25**:
It depends on your sonar sensors. What kind of output signal do they have? Analog signal, SPI, I2C, USB? A good starting point would be [wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) if you want to use the GPIO

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-25**:
Thanks john for your fast reply! I am using a HC-SR04. It works fine with the digital pins of my Raspberry pi. So I think it's digital.

**Comment by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) on 2016-04-25**:
Yes, it is a digital signal, where you can measure the time and calculate the distance to the object. A short google search also found [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=92220&p=644369) Pi driver. But either with this driver or wiringPi, you have tow write the node yourself.

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-25**:
Okay, so all I have to do is to include this driver in the node right? Also can you take a look at my other question?

**Comment by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) on 2016-04-26**:
You need to compile and load the driver first. It is documented on the [github](https://github.com/zhanisch/hc-sr04_driver) page. I cannot answer your second question, I don't know anything about mapping.

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-26**:
So it can also be written in python? It would be the same? And in that case I need not need any external GPIO library like the wiring Pi because it has its own library, RPi.GPIO. Is it possible?

**Comment by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) on 2016-04-27**:
It should be possible. I haven't used RPi.GPIO yet, but after a short google search I found that it also supports interrupts ([described here](http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio)). In theory it will work, but I don't know how precise it will be.

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-27**:
okay. So its better with wiringpi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Summary of the comments:
To use the Pi's GPIO in ROS, you have to use a third party library, for example [wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) (C++) or [RPi.GPIO](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO) (Python). Both examples support interrupts (examples: [wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/reference/priority-interrupts-and-threads/), [RPi.GPIO](http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio)), which you need to measure the time the sound signal of your HC-SR04 needs to travel to an object and back to the sensor.

Alternatively, there's a driver for the Raspberry Pi and the HC-SR04 [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=92220&p=644369) ([Github](https://github.com/zhanisch/hc-sr04_driver)). I have never used this driver, so I cannot say if it works or not.

Also think about the fact, that the default Raspbian is not a realtime operating system. The measured times are not consistent and may vary depending on the Pi's CPU load. You should test the variation in your system before trusting any measurements.

---

Originally posted by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) with karma: 305 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mukut_noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/26182/mukut_noob/) on 2016-04-27**:
Yes I have tested it and I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my Pi. And I will be use either wiringpi or RPi.GPIO. I think it would be more precise.